# I'm trying to list down all start_date and end_date, but it says time data 'Totals' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df.loc[:, 'START_DATE*'] = df['START_DATE*'].apply(lambda x:pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
df.loc[:, 'END_DATE*'] = df['END_DATE*'].apply(lambda x:pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
```

and the coding said

```
ValueError: time data 'Totals' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
```

Comment: Hey there, you should provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), try sharing the output of `df.head().to_dict('records')`

Comment: Without seeing what your data looks like, all we can say about this is that the data in `x` doesn't match the format `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M` that your code has told `strptime()` to accept.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.